# How to combine 2 different cron expressions?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

I need to schedule a process on UiPath Orchestrator. The process should triggered at 9AM, 10.30AM, 12PM, 14PM, 15PM and 16PM in weekdays.

If there was no 10.30AM, I could apply the schedule in one cron expression.

But now, I can only cover this issue with 2 cron expressions.

How do I combine this two cron expressions as one?

```
0 0 9,12,14,15,16 ? * MON-FRI *

0 30 10 ? * MON-FRI *
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to combine two Cron-Expressions under one command.

Alternatively, what you can do is to create **two Schedules** for the **same Process** one per your expressions. Check image below:

[image]

Keep in mind that you need to set different names as each Schedule name needs to be unique