# Combine cron expressions

Tags: service, cron, hangfire

I have two cron expressions which are for:

```
last day of month : 0 0 0 L * *
every sunday      : 0 0 0 * * 0
```

I need the combined expression to trigger every last day of month and also every sunday but it should trigger only 1 time when the last day of month is sunday, not twice. How can i combine these two expressions?

Best Regards

Comment: Doesn't look like you can combine two expressions: [How to combine 2 different cron expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56219670/)